# Change active sheetname based on a cell value of that sheet automatically

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I found this code on google which can help me to change current tab name based on a cell value of this sheet. However, I have to run this macro code manually each time. How can I modify this code to make it change automatically after entering value in a cell or at least tab's name changes as typing. Here is the code:

```
Sub myTabName()
    ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("C3")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place this in the sheet code pane

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(False, False) = "C3" Then ActiveSheet.name = ActiveSheet.Range("C3")
End Sub
```